# Gnuplot won't read $ character

Tags: gnuplot

I have a very simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot << EOF
set term postscript portrait
set output 'out.ps'

plot 'data_file' u 3:($2==0.0 ? $2:1/0)

EOF
```

where `data_file` looks like this:

```
  O4     -1.20     -0.33     -5.20  
O9.5     -1.10     -0.30     -3.60  
  B0     -1.08     -0.30     -3.25  
B0.5     -1.00     -0.28     -2.60  
B1.5     -0.90     -0.25     -2.10  
B2.5     -0.80     -0.22     -1.50  
  B3     -0.69     -0.20     -1.10  
....
```

I have tried several combinations and I still get the same error always:

```
gnuplot> plot 'S-K_data' u 3:(==0.0 ? :1/0)
                          ^
         line 0: invalid expression
```

As you can see, it's not reading the `$2` characters and I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an unquoted here doc, variables are expanded.  Try

```
gnuplot << 'EOF'
```

or

```
gnuplot << \EOF
```

Which you choose is a matter of personal preference (you can use any quoting mechanism, so `EOF""` works, but the two above are the most common). When the heredoc delimiter is unquoted, the shell is expanding `$2` to the second parameter passed to the script.  (Try calling the script with 2 arguments.)  When the heredoc delimiter is quoted, no such expansion takes place.

Comment: Brilliant.  I never knew this existed.  (Now I need to go back through all my scripts removing `\$1` etc).