# Using different types of variables for piped gnuplot script

Tags: perl, variables, gnuplot, heredoc

I am trying to pipe a gnuplot script in perl to get some plots. My `data.dat` looks like:

```
1       5       2
2       3       9
3       9       6
4       -4      8
5       -3      4
6       11      2
7       0       -3
8       -8      -2
9       1       0
10      22      0
```

I tried this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    
use strict;

my $type="png";

open(my $GP,'| gnuplot');

print {$GP} << "__GNUPLOT__";

set style data lines
#set logscale y
set terminal $type
set output 'pic.$type'
plot "data.dat" u 1:2, "" u 1:3

__GNUPLOT__

close $GP;
```

My aim is to plot the log scale. Because of the negative data, I wanted to use `plot "data.dat" u 1:(abs($2)), "" u 1:(abs($3))`. So I want to get access to my perl-script variables and the gnuplot variables `$2` `$3`. Not quoting the heredoc `__GNUPLOT__` isn't working for this. I found those posts which treat a similar topic:

- [gnuplot wont read $ character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11228232/2622293)
- [using variables inside bash heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938198/2622293)

I don't know if this issue is the same for bash. I wasn't trying it yet, but would be interested there too. I just want to learn more about the general problem with piping, quoting and different types of variables.

Comment: There is a Module for Gnuplot. It basically does what you do manually in your script and offers an interface. [Chart::Gnuplot](https://metacpan.org/module/Chart::Gnuplot). The downside is that it needs GhostScript an imagemagick to generate png images. I never used gnuplot without this module so I don't know if this behaviour is normal.

Comment: If it is possible I would stick to the standard release of Gnuplot without installing additional modules. Thx for your input though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `$2` is only a shorthand for `column(2)`. So if you are having problems with escaping, use

```
plot "data.dat" u 1:(abs(column(2))), "" u 1:(abs(column(3)))
```

Comment: Well this was easy, thank you :) Do you also know what are the differences by quoting for piping?